# UIPageControl has clear background color but is still cutting out overlapping text view

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a UIPageViewController where I have a button close to the page control indicator dots.
In this first screenshot I've made the background color of the page control red to illustrate how the page control and button are overlapping:

[image]

However if I change the background to be a clear color then the text within the button is still being chopped off at the bottom by the page indicator.

I've additionally tried setting the page indicator's Opacity to NO but it makes no difference:

[image]

The control is being configured like this:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[pageControl setOpaque:NO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];;
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[pageControl setOpaque:NO];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,100);
pageControl.numberOfPages=3;
pageControl.currentPage=2;
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

[image: Screenshot]